# Capture click event in fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

I have a `ViewPager` and a `Fragment` is there in the viewpager with 4 buttons. I want to check if any button was clicked before swiping to different page.I tried doing it by ontouchevent but without any success.I tried this piece of code.

```
    l1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    l2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    l3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    l4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Please help me in deciding as how i can achieve this.Since i want to know if user clicked any button before moving to next page.

Comment: `i want to know if user clicked any button before moving to next page` . To do that just set a Click listener on Button and set a boolean Flag that  its clicked . Why you need `OnTouchListener`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a flag on class level "isAnyButtonClicked" and also need to set onClickListener for each button. in each button onClickListener you need to set that flag. Like

```
 boolean isAnyButtonClicked = false; // you can declare it as static as well

 // Now in your fragment that is loaded in viewpager, set clicklistner for each button


 l1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        isAnyButtonClicked = true;
    }
});


l2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        isAnyButtonClicked = true;
    }
});
```

Now Add Viewpager onScroll Listener to detect swipe event in your activity or fragment where you have view pager

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
               if (isAnyButtonClicked) {
                    // Do whatever you want :)
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}
    });
```